# select top selling size by product group from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table called `Orders`. There are three columns: `CustomerID`, `ProductGroup`, `Size`.

How can I get `TOP` selling size by `ProductGroup` from this table?

I can do it 1 by 1 with

```
SELECT TOP 1 Count(customerid) as customers, ProductGroup, Size 
FROM Orders 
WHERE ProductGroup = xxx 
GROUP BY ProductGroup, Size
ORDER BY Count(customerid) DESC
```

However, I would like to get full list at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but it may help you.

```
Declare @temp table(CustomerID int, ProductGroup varchar(10), Size int)

insert into @temp
Select 1,'ABC',15 union all
Select 2,'ABC',10 union all
Select 3,'XYZ',12 union all
Select 4,'ABC',15 union all
Select 3,'XYZ',12 union all
Select 3,'XYZ',12 union all
Select 3,'XYZ',15 union all
Select 3,'XYZ',11 union all
Select 3,'XYZ',12 

Select * from (
Select RANK() Over(PARTITION BY ProductGroup order by customers desc) RankVal,customers,ProductGroup, Size 
from (
SELECT Count(CustomerID) as customers, ProductGroup, Size 
FROM  @temp 
GROUP BY ProductGroup, Size
) T
)T1
WHERE RankVal = 1
```

Comment: Then i will get all results. What i want is that i get table with 1 bestseller size per productgroup. Your sql will give me all sizes fro productgroup

Answer (score 1):

Please check following SELECT query with [SQL Count using Partition By clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT 
        Distinct ProductGroup, Size, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (Partition By ProductGroup, Size) cnt
    FROM Customers
)
select 
    ProductGroup, Size, cnt
from (
    select *, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By ProductGroup Order By cnt desc)
    from cte
) t 
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the top selling product for every `ProductGroup`. The way to achieve this, is to use a `group by`, e.g. via

```
SELECT ProductGroup, MAX(size)
FROM orders
GROUP BY ProductGroup
```

This way you get a result table with one column per `ProductGroup` and the maximum of the sizes by this product group.

Comment: That is wrong i think. As you take just max size not the qty. What i need is to get in every ProductGroup the most bought size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the MAX operator and put your SQL in a subquery, like this (not tested):

```
  SELECT MAX(customers), ProductGroup, Size FROM Orders GROUP BY ProductGroup, Size HAVING MAX(customers) = 
    SELECT MAX(customers) AS myMax FROM (
        SELECT Count(customerid) as customers, ProductGroup, Size
        FROM Orders 
        GROUP BY ProductGroup, Size) AS O
    GROUP BY ProductGroup, Size
```

Comment: Here is the problem for example if i have productgroup 01 and there are 2 sizes like 42 and 44 then this query cannot group them. I have to take most selling size. Otherwise it cannot get TOP i will give me 2 rows not 1.

Comment: @vovkjn I've removed the Size grouping in both queries. This will count products ignoring size. Is this that you want?

Comment: not really. I want size also. So it should be like THE TOP SELLING SIZE per productgroup. The problem is that it is not possible to group by productgroup and size with MAX function counting customers. It should be something that takes ONLY 1 TOP SELLING size

Comment: @vovkjn I think that you need another subquery. You can try to work around my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregate function max() to select the highest size and group it according to ProductGroup.

```
SELECT COUNT(customerid) as customers, ProductGroup, MAX(Size) FROM 
    Orders WHERE Size IN (SELECT MAX(Size) FROM Orders) GROUP BY ProductGroup
    ORDER BY customerid DESC;
```

Note that this query has not been tested yet and I wonder if why do you need to get the count of customerid if your selecting only the highest Size per ProductGroup.

Comment: Not the highest size but the most bought size

Comment: @vovkjn I knew it! you could try this instead: SELECT COUNT(customerid) as customers, ProductGroup, Size FROM 
    Orders WHERE Size IN (SELECT MAX(Size) FROM Orders GROUP BY ProductGroup) GROUP BY ProductGroup,Size
    ORDER BY 1 DESC;